# WP_Query to get posts in a specific category and post format

Tags: wp-query, loop

I've been trying to utilize either `WP_Query` or `get_posts` to pull out the most recent post that's both in a specific category and of a specific post format.

```
<?php 
$singargs = array(
'numberposts' => 1,
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array ( 'gift-of-the-day' ),
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy', => 'post_format',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'aside'),
    )
)
);
$singPost = new WP_Query( $singargs );
foreach ( $singPost as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<aside>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
</aside>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, the foreach is wrong. That's not a proper Loop. You should be doing `while ($singPost->have_posts()) : $singPost->the_post();` instead

Comment: Also, `aside` is not a proper post format taxonomy slug, so you won't get any results in this query. The correct one to use there is `post-format-aside`.

Comment: I had tried `post-format-aside` prior to asking, but had no success. I also tried swapping out the `foreach` for the `while` loop syntax you suggested, with no success. (Leaving `post-format-aside` of course.)

Answer (score 1):

Two problems i see:
change `aside` to `post-format-aside` 
and since you are using foreach loop change `new WP_Query( $singargs );` to  `get_posts( $singargs );` so your code sould look like this:

```
<?php 
$singargs = array(
'numberposts' => 1,
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array ( 'gift-of-the-day' ),
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy', => 'post_format',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'post-format-aside'),
    )
)
);
$singPost = get_posts( $singargs );
foreach ( $singPost as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<aside>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
</aside>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: I've tried this code verbatim, using the `get_posts()` and `foreach`. It didn't work. I also tried it with @Otto's suggestions of using a `while` loop with the syntax he suggested. That also did not work.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. Perhaps you don't have any posts that match?

Comment: I have a post that is in the category with a slug "gift-of-the-day", that is set to the post format "aside", that is published.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just use something like :

```
$args = array('category' => 1 );
$all_posts = get_posts( $args);
foreach ($all_posts as $this_post) {
    if ( has_post_format( 'aside' ) ) {
        echo '<aside><h2>' . $this_post->title . '</h2></aside>';
        break;
        }
}
```

Could be some mistake in the code, but the idea is to first get the posts in wanted category, then parse it and take the first post that has the wanted post format (in case you couldn't make your code work).

Sorry if i'm wrong !